# How can I control where a new instance of an Excel application appears on my screen

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

When I open a new instance of Excel, it does not open with the same window size and the same location on the screen as before. I would ideally like it to open with the same size and position as it was when I closed the last open window. The size and position seems to be somewhat randomly determined. Is there a way to control this?

Comment: Natively no, that is not how Excel works.